# Struts -1 action being called multiple times sometimes and restof times it works fine

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

this is my action file

```
 public ActionForward NEW(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
// some code for page intializtion 
return mapping.findForward("NEW");
}
 public ActionForward SAVE(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
     {
         //code to save data
   return this.NEW(mapping, form, request, response);
      }
```

after saving data new function is called. my code was working fine till some months back,no changes were made at business logic but now sometimes code saves same set of data multiple times.
On 1st time when bug was reported it saved data 9  times
after some days saved data 158 times , 54 times , 39 times, 305 times, 2 times. there is no data related problem. rest of the time code works fine. in past 8 months only 9 times this bug has occurred. the code saves some 100 record per day.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. Unrelated, but I'd recommend sticking to normal Java naming conventions; "unusual" names make code harder to think about.

Comment: what more information should i gve you so that you can help me. In new function i am setting some values in formbean and fetching some data from DB . in Save function i am saving my data. what "unusual " names means ?

Comment: "Unusual" means naming methods with all capital letters; all-caps, by convention, is used only for things like `final static` references. If the problem is multiple calls, then it's likely it's being called multiple times. If the problem is multiple saves with a *single* call, then there's something wrong with the code that does the saving.

Comment: the save code is working fine. the code to save data is written in my DAO file. My action files calls a.java which calls b.java which calls DAO.java. what i have found is all the code runs fine, it comes back to action file's save function which in turn calls new function , after new function is called then again save function which shouldn'thave been the scenario. I am unable to understand why from new function it is not returning to jsp and if it is returning to jsp then why save function is again called without event being generated again.

Comment: If there was problem with business logic then the there should have been a pattern in multiple calls , or bug occurrence should have some pattern .

Comment: I don't think there's any way to diagnose with the information provided. If it's intermittent I would check the server logs to see if the endpoint is being hit multiple times; without any context I don't see any reason why it would randomly get stuck in some sort of loop, particularly since the number of hits is variable. That said, calling an action method within another action method is a strange pattern and not how I'd do it. If there's any logic that might cause this in the action it's not visible here, so can't pursue that path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Its an old project and the code is not written by me, the jsp page also contains java code. The log is too big to share and tough to understand. I have found that it returns to jsp page since SOP's at jsp  are written in log and again action is called. So the problem is jsp is calling action again and again in a single click of save button.

Comment: Then you'll need to follow the logic of the `NEW` and `SAVE` actions to see if there's any reason it would get stuck in a loop. And you should still check the server log to see if the endpoint is being hit multiple times.

Comment: yes i have seen server log it hits the jsp multipletimes. I will see if I can change Call of New function from save.  Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm talking about the server request log--is the endpoint being hit multiple times?

Comment: i have checked my server access log --------   [12/Sep/2020:12:47:28 +0530] POST "PATH FOR MY ACTION" HTTP/1.1 200 49701 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0 "https://SITE_ADDRESS/PATH OF MY ACTION"      ----------                 this line is 56 times in my server access log and this time data has been saved 56 times

Comment: If the server log shows an access then this is a client-side issue (unless you're redirecting via action config, then it's still a question). If the server is hit 56 times then something is hitting it 56 times.